# Resize Cesium viewer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, cesiumjs

Currently developing a Webapp using Cesium and Bootstrap.

Problem is that Cesium viewer is not resizable. Only solution I found to limit it to 50% of the window is `overflow: hidden;` in css. You will understand that this can lead to an unnecessary use of resources because we are doing a simple cache-misère.

Any clue to resize Cesium viewer?

```js
  var cesiumContainer = document.getElementById("cesiumContainer");

  var ellipsoid = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84;

  var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
    sceneMode: Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D,
    infoBox: false,
    geocoder: false,
    timeline: false,
    animation: false,
    homeButton: false,
    scene3DOnly: true,
    baseLayerPicker: false,
    sceneModePicker: false,
    fullscreenButton: false,
    projectionPicker: false,
    selectionIndicator: false,
    navigationHelpButton: false,
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false
  });
```

```css
html,
body,
#cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.11/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css">

    <script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>

      <div class="col">
        This must take 50% of height.
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your mention of "not resizable" when you're resizing it to 50% here in your question.  Do you mean it won't automatically size?  That's true, but you can use an outer construct like Flex Box to control such automatic sizing.

Comment: Or you can place it inside ye olde HTML tables, they still have some good old sizing options on them.  But really modern CSS should be able to do whatever is needed, I guess I'm not clear on what's needed here.

Comment: Actually, the Cesium viewer seems to have a fix height/width ratio. So as it takes devide width first, it doesnt not respect the 50% height condition. I need to overflow:hidden the canvas to limit it but it is not a viable solution imo.

Comment: As the hidden command will hide parts of complex 3D models, the problem is that this might result in an overuse of ressources...

Comment: That's very odd.  The globe shouldn't have any fixed hight/width ratio.  Can you post a complete working sample somewhere?

Comment: @emackey I edited the question with a working snippet.

Answer (score -1):

[Responsive DIVs in CesiumViewer [CesiumJS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278693/responsive-divs-in-cesiumviewer-cesiumjs)

As i said here where i have a very similar problem, using reactjs u can use cesium as a react component and render the cesium map and it size in function of the browser size.

Comment: Problem is that I don't want to make Cesium full size but partially. Moreover, your answer only points to another question that had not been successfully answered.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enogh,  to have a partial window with the cesium viewer i choose to use react js inside my applicaton, in this way i was able to give not only the size i want also i was able to exchange datas with cesium component much more easy